# Authenticating dropbox using SAML response token

Tags: spring-security, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

We are trying to implement a logic to connect dropbox using azure SAML response token.
We have already authenticated user in our application using saml with the same response token we want to redirect it to dropbox home page without providing dropbox creds as authentication is already done using SAML earlier.
We are only able to find oauth2 code to connect with dropbox, not able to find a code where we can use saml token response to connect with dropbox.

Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks in advance :) :)

Answer (score 0):

The following help articles may be useful:

- https://help.dropbox.com/teams-admins/admin/sso-admin
- https://help.dropbox.com/accounts-billing/security/supported-identity-providers
- https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/third-party/microsoft-azure-ad
- https://help.dropbox.com/teams-admins/team-member/sso-adfs-2